# How can I produce a select tag using JSTL or Standard Actions in a JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I want to make a select tag in a JSP, where the options are an Enumeration (for example, all US States).  Is their a tag in JSTL or a standard tag that can do this, without manually iterating through the list?

Comment: You should really clarify the term "manually" more here. You should also clarify what's wrong with c:forEach. It dynamically iterates over the list as well without that you need to know the amount of items beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't in JSTL. However many frameworks provide such additional tags:

- [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/Select.html) - `<s:select>`
- [Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706660/spring-mvc-formselect-tag-multiple-selections-not-binding-correctly) - `<form:select>`
- [JSF](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneMenu.html) - `<h:selectOneMenu>`

Comment: No? He just didn't want to manually iterate through the list. Or we must all have another interpretation of "manually". Anyway, to complete the list, in JSF there's a `h:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: I'll use Struts2.  I forgot that I could use the struts tags, without using the Struts framework.

Comment: @BalusC - I understood that 'manually' means 'by `c:forEach`', but it could well mean anything else.

Answer (score 16):

Certainly, in [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`) there's the [`c:forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag. You'll only have to convert the (old fashioned) `Enumeration` to a modern `List` or perhaps `Enum` if it's hardcoded in Java. You can if necessary grab [`Collections#list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list-java.util.Enumeration-) for this if the `Enumeration` is to be obtained from an unchangeable 3rd party API.

Here's a demo how the `<c:forEach>` can then be used:

```html
<select name="country">
   <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
       <option value="${country.code}" ${param.country eq country.code ? 'selected' : ''}>${country.name}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The `${countries}` should refer a `List<Country>` or `Country[]` which has been put in any of the `page`, `request`, `session` or `application` scopes — of which the `application` scope is the most straightforward choice, as a list of countries is supposed to be an application wide constant. You could use a `ServletContextListener` to load it once and put in application scope on application's startup. The `Country` is in this example just a Javabean (model) class with at least two properties.

#### See also:

- [Populating cascading dropdown lists in JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet/)
- [Set selected option on existing select tag with jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008698/set-selected-option-on-existing-select-tag-with-jstl/)
- [Using enum in JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739918/using-enum-in-jstl/) - [Can I access the values of an enum class from a JSP using EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240722/can-i-access-the-values-of-an-enum-class-from-a-jsp-using-el/)