# dropdown list;servlet Problem

Tags: servlets

I try to excute the servlet code given, like an exemple to understand how it works.
BUT I did not understand from where the attribut optionDAO and what is the necessity to use it.
The find method seems like the given by hibernate in package".base".
What should I really do to skip this.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to give some more details here. We do not have the context to understand what you are asking?

Comment: I bet he's talking about my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet In the future, you should be really more clear about that, user294750.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a fictive code example according the DAO pattern with a self-explaining classname and methodname which you need to write/implement yourself. E.g.

```
public class OptionDAO {
    public List<Option> find(String dd, String val) { 
        // Write code here yourself which does the desired task: returning
        // a list of options based on the given dropdown id and value. 
        return options;
    }
}
```

The way how to do it namely differs per environment, ORM libraries used, datamodel design, etc.. that it's impossible to give a concrete code example. Examples how to do it with "plain vanilla" JDBC can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html). Examples how to do it with Hibernate can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/). Examlpes how to do it with JPA can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).