# iterating through java collection using jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am starting with this object,

```
public class myTO {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    }
```

Which is used in this object

```
public myCombiTO {
    private myTO myTO;

    private List<String> valueList;
    private List<String> displayList;
}
```

I create a list of these objects

```
List<myCombiTO> myCombiTOList = getMyCombiTOList();
```

I use this list to set a jsp page attribute

```
request.setAttribute("myAttrList", myCombiTOList);
```

And forward to the jsp page. I then use jquery and jstl to populate a drop down from this list

```
<select name="mYSelect" id="mySelect">
     <c:forEach var="myVar" items="${myAttrList}">
          <option value="${myVar.myTO.id}" >
               <c:out value="${myVar.myTO.name}" />
          </option>
    </c:forEach>    
</select>
```

My problem is I want to populate a second drop down using jquery with the values from mycombiTO.getValueList(). so far I have this

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
        var myJSList = ${myAttrList};
        var chosenGroup = $("#mySelect").val();
        var valueArray = myJSList.get(chosenGroup).valueList;
        var displayArray = myJSList.get(chosenGroup).displayList;
        var items = {'display':[displayArray], 'value':[valueArray]};

        //now populate drop downs

        $.populateSelect($('#myselect').get(0), items);

    });

jQuery.populateSelect = function(element,items) {
    $.each(items, function() {
            element.options[element.options.length]  = new Option(this.display,this.value);
          });
};
```

However its not working please help.  I am having trouble creating the javascript object based on two arrays.  Hwoever ideally I would want to reference a java map from jquery using key/value pairs. Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're passing in `items` which is an object with only two key/value pairs, so the `$.each()` is running for only two iterations. And for those iterations, `this.display` and `this.value` refer to the entire arrays.

One option would be to simply pass the `displayArray` and `valueArray` in to the `populateSelect()`, and iterate over those:

```
jQuery.populateSelect = function(element,displayArray,valueArray) {
    $.each(displayArray, function(i,val) {
        element.options[element.options.length]  = new Option( displayArray[i] ,valueArray[i] );
    });
};
```

Going back to your original code, you could also do this:

```
jQuery.populateSelect = function(element,items) {
    $.each(items.display, function(i,val) {
        element.options[element.options.length]  = new Option( items.display[i] ,items.value[i] );
    });
};
```

Comment: Yeah OK thanks; I was hoping for a mechanism to just use the one datastructure for displayArray and valueArray ... ?

Comment: @batthink - Sure. You could go back to your original code, and iterate over `items.display` instead of `items`. I'll update my answer with that. Another solution would be to create an array of objects, and iterate over that array instead of creating an object with the arrays inside.

Answer (score 1):

I think your java code should provide a json version of your objects. You could then either insert the whole myCombiTOList in your jsp, or get a single myCombiTO object with an ajax request in the change function.