# How to get value to dropdown from database using ajax?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have dropdown with some optional value.if change the those value based on that will display another dropdown with value from database.I am doing this process in jsp page.First dropdown values are static(coded in jsp).but second dropdown values are come from database when changeevent of first dropdown.

Here i need to implement ajax or javascript ? Could you give me examples of this drop down.

Comment: Duplicate of [Populating child dropdownlists in JSP/Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JQuery and Ajax pretty easily. Check out 
http://www.chazzuka.com/experiments/jquery-dropdown/

for an example

Answer (score 0):

You have two drop down

```
<select id="first" onchange="get_result();" >
    somevale
</select>


<select name="second" >
</select>
```

now you need to give body to our get_result function

```
function get_result()
{
      var value = $("#id).val();
      JQuery.ajax("some_url",{ id : value }, function(){} )
}
```

This way you can do this. You specific check JQuery tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

> Here i need to implement ajax or
>   javascript ?

Ajax.

> Could you give me examples of this drop down.

JQuery works fine. I found DWR framework to be easier to understand for newcomers to Ajax. You can look at tutorials on that [here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html).