# I want on select value in one combo the other will fill on same page

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I Have two combo box And I want on select value in one combo the other will fill on same page
and the value come from database in both combos.

any idea

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Populating child dropdownlists in JSP/Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript, preferably jQuery.

When the first value is selected, make an AJAX call to get the second value based on the selection.  When the callback returns, fill in the second UI element.