# Sending ListBox selected values as Hidden Field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, servlets

I want to be able to send all the selected values from a listbox as a hidden field using JQuery.
I was able to send/retrieve a single value on form submission.

If anyone can share some code snippet, that would help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code for this.use http://jsfiddle.net/ for sample code display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not so clear what you are really asking for. There is no "multiple selection dropdownlist" in HTML. To have a multiselect you need to specify

```
<select id="foobar" multiple>
```

that will create a `listbox` where you may select multiple elements. Calling

```
var sel = $('#foobar').val();
```

will return an `Array` of selected items.

**edit**

To get the text from each option, use `.map()` or `jQuery.map()`. Example:

```
var sel = $('#foobar').children('option:selected').map(function(i,e){
    return e.innerText;
}).get();
```

That will create an Array containing the text of all selected entrys.

Comment: I meant the listbox, sorry for the typos. The .val() call doesn't give me the text of the selected options as the listbox is a dependent dropdown and consists of a JSON String. So, .val gives me the integer index and not the text. I use the option #3 listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet in order to populate the child dropdown.

Comment: 10 on 10. I am still new here, so was unable to post formatted code in a limited span of time. Not sure if Ctrl+K on comments really works for code formatting or not. FYI.. this was my first attempt at JQuery and am liking it.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no need to do like that. You was apparently using [`request.getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [`request.getParameterValues()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) and wondering why it returned only the first value.

Just fix your servlet code accordingly:

```
String[] selectedItems = request.getParameterValues("dropdownname");
```

No need for ugly JS/jQuery hacks to send them all as single parameter. In future questions, try to ask how to solve a problem instead of how to achieve a solution which may after all not be the right solution per se.