# Displaying a submenu based on choice in some other menu?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, dwr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populating child dropdownlists in JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet)

In my JSP page, I have used one `div` that adds some rows dynamically. Inside this `div`, there are dropdowns to select country, state and city values. On the basis of country selected, its corresponding states and cities should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this space [Populating Child Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet)