# Creating dynamic frames in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

Hi 
 I am new to front end development using JSPs. I have a question. In my project, I have to a form with a drop down box and 4 submit buttons for different actions. When a choose a value in the drop down box and click 1 of the submit buttons, another drop down box with a submit button should appear.When I choose an option in the second drop down box and click submit, data from the database should be queried and displayed in the same page. It is the same with the 3 other submit buttons too. How best to implement this? I am not using any frameworks- only jsp and servlets. My idea is to use 2 iframes in the jsp which display the dynamic data.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet

Answer (score 1):

You can create one big form containing data for all possible fields no matter which option is selected. Submit the form with necessary fragment filled for any selected option. Then on server just check what is selected and process the data accordingly.