# For a particular selected value from a drop-down box, Display its corresponding values in drop down list?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have two fields in a webpage. Both are composite primary keys. Out of that when I select one field (eg. out of a list of countries I select - India), the second field should display all the values corresponding to the previous field (eg. after selecting India I should get all the states in another drop-down menu).

I'm implementing this using JSP and Ajax.

Can someone please help me with this or send me the code snippets.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2263996/615754

Comment: @ nnnnnn : I m trying using JSP.. Can u please help me with JSP codes?

Answer (score 1):

Neal,
There are various codes available like this. Just do googling.
Try with [link](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/comboSelect.shtml)