# display corresponding number of a dropdownlist based on selection using jsp

Tags: html, jsp

i have 2 dropdown menus,one is with a list of car names and another one is with list of number.if i select the any one of the car names from 1st ddl the second one should show the corresponding number related to the selection.

```
<form method="post" action="sample2.jsp">
<select name="sel1">
<option value="Alto">Alto</option>
<option value="Esteem">Esteem</option>
<option value="Honda City">Honda City</option>
<option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="sel2">
<option value="1.1">1.1</option>
<option value="1.2">1.2</option>
<option value="1.3">1.3</option>
<option value="1.4">1.4</option>
</select>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

example:
alto->1.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating child dropdownlists in JSP/Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet)

Comment: it is possible with javascript alone.?

Comment: Options 2 and 3 in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could it with jQuery as below:

```
$('#sel1').change(function(){    
    var index = $('#sel1').attr('selectedIndex');
    $('#sel2').attr('selectedIndex', index);        
});
```

See example at: http://jsfiddle.net/a2crA/1/