# Filling HTML <select> dropdown list in JSP with values fetched from database in Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a database `flights_DB` containing a table called `Passengers`.  Each passenger is uniquely identified by his passport number.

I would like to create a drop-down list containing all the passport numbers in the table `Passengers`. How can I achieve this using JSP and Servlets?

Comment: Do you want to create the dropdown asynchronously or statically?

Comment: Erm..  What is the difference between the two exactly?

Comment: This question is way too broad. At which step exactly are you stucking? Connecting the DB? Executing the SQL query? Collecting the results? Calling the class/method with this all from inside the servlet? Passing the results to JSP? Calling the JSP to present the results? Accessing the results in JSP? Iterating over the results in JSP? Presenting the results in HTML? Calling the page itself? Invoking the servlet on the call? Etc..etc.. Please go through a basic tutorial to grasp the basic concepts first.

Comment: I know how to connect to a database, executing queries, results etc. from a servlet.  I just want to know how I bind the data to the drop-down list on page load.

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[jsp]` and/or `[servlets]` tag which you've placed on the question yourself until a black info box shows up and then click therein the *info* link. You end up in our tag wiki pages which contains some good Hello World examples and several links to sane learning resources.

Comment: For instance, where in the servlet do I put the code to connect to the database, execute the query and fetch the results?  How do I then bind the data to the drop-down list?

Comment: @Matthey: The first means "build the dropdown with javascript" the other is "build it with JSP on the server side"

Comment: Ok.  I understand now.  I would like the latter approach, that is, building it on the server side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you've the model and DB part already finished (as per the comments on the question), just create a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) class and implement the `doGet()` method accordingly. It's relatively simple, just retrieve the list of passengers from the DB, store it in request scope and forward to the JSP which should present it. The below example assumes that you're using EJB/JPA as service/DB layer, but whatever service/DB layer you use, you should ultimately end up getting a `List<Passenger>` from it anyway.

```
@WebServlet("/passengers")
public class Passengers extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private PassengerService service;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Passenger> passengers = service.list();
        request.setAttribute("passengers", passengers);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/passengers.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Create a [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) file `/WEB-INF/passengers.jsp` which uses [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it, printing a new HTML `<option>` everytime:

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<select name="passenger">
    <c:forEach items="${passengers}" var="passenger">
        <option value="${passenger.id}"><c:out value="${passenger.name}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

*(this example assumes the `Passenger` entity to have `id` and `name` properties)*

That should basically be it. Just open the page by invoking the servlet's URL like so http://example.com/contextpath/passengers.

#### See also:

- [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)
- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc)
- [Populating cascading dropdown lists in JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet)