# Set selected option on existing select tag with jstl

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

So I have a select for the grade on each subject. It's predefined and hence I don't have to store grades as a table in the database. I have a list of qualifications and I using jstl for each like this: `<c:forEach items="${qualificationdetails}" var="qd">`.

For each item I am producing a select like this.

```
<select class="grade" title="Grade Obtained">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   <option value="D">D</option>
   <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to set the selected option using my variable **qd** ? something like

```
<option value="${qd.grade}" selected="selecetd">${qd.grade}</option>
```

This will add a duplicate option to the select. I think it would a bit "clunky" to make an array with the grades and send it accross for generating the options. Any ideas ?

Comment: When do you know which value should be selected as default, and how do you intend to parse it to the page? Because I am thinking that you could to what you proposed there at the end of the post while iterating, and not after the iteration is done, such that you do not have duplicates. Does the "qd" hold a flag that states which should be selected?

Comment: Yes, qd has and id, name, grade and year. All of this information is available via qd. So the grade property of any given qd will have a grade value and that should be my selected value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could just let JSP render the `selected` attribute conditionally.

```
<select class="grade" title="Grade Obtained">
    <option value="1" ${qd.grade == '1' ? 'selected' : ''}>1</option>
    <option value="2" ${qd.grade == '2' ? 'selected' : ''}>2</option>
    <option value="3" ${qd.grade == '3' ? 'selected' : ''}>3</option>
    <option value="A" ${qd.grade == 'A' ? 'selected' : ''}>A</option>
    <option value="B" ${qd.grade == 'B' ? 'selected' : ''}>B</option>
    <option value="C" ${qd.grade == 'C' ? 'selected' : ''}>C</option>
    <option value="D" ${qd.grade == 'D' ? 'selected' : ''}>D</option>
    <option value="E" ${qd.grade == 'E' ? 'selected' : ''}>E</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively, you could just create a collection/array of grades and store it in the application scope so that it's available in EL so that you can loop over it using `<c:forEach>`. I'm not sure how that would be "clunky". You could use `<c:set>` to store them commaseparated and use `fn:split()` to split them for `<c:forEach>`.

```
<c:set var="grades" value="1,2,3,A,B,C,D,E" scope="application" />
<select class="grade" title="Grade Obtained">
    <c:forEach items="${fn:split(grades, ',')}" var="grade">
        <option value="${grade}" ${qd.grade == grade ? 'selected' : ''}>${grade}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This way you end up with more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.