# Java Spring Form: map one entity to another entity in JSP form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, hibernate-mapping, spring-form

I have two entities: Country and Contact:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="countries")
@NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Country c")
public class Country implements Serializable {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String code;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="countryBean")
    private List<Contact> contacts;
//...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="contacts")
@NamedQuery(name="Contact.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Contact c")
public class Contact implements Serializable {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String city;

    private String street;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="countries_id")
    private Country countryBean;
//...
}
```

I need to add new contact and select existing country from database.

There is part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/contact/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String contactAddGetPage(Model model) {

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    model.addAttribute("contact", contact);

    List<Country> countries = countryManager.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("countries", countries);

    return "contactAdd";        
}

@RequestMapping(value="/contact/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String contactAddSave(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("contact") Contact contact, BindingResult result, 
            Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "error");
            return "contactAdd";
        }

        contactManager.save(contact);           
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "ok");
        return "redirect:/contact";     
    }
```

And "contactAdd.jsp" JSP using Spring Form:

```
<c:url var="sendToUrl" value="/contact/add" />
<form:form method="post" action="${sendToUrl}" commandName="contact">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="street">Street</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="street"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="street"></form:errors></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="city"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="city"></form:errors></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="countryBean">Country</form:label></td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="countryBean">
                    <form:options items="${countries}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
                </form:select>
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="countryBean"></form:errors></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

If I go to form page in www browser it looks ok. There is html select with name of countries from database.

But if I click on "Add" button, I get for "Country" form select:

*Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.example.test.entity.Country for property countryBean; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.example.test.entity.Country] for property countryBean: no matching editors or conversion strategy found*

I understand error. I must convert country to "Country" class. But how can I do it?

Comment: I try http://stackoverflow.com/a/724523/1974494, http://empire5.com/development/binding-a-custom-object-in-spring-3/ but it not work. Now I get "Property countryBean threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException" :-(

Answer (score 0):

PropertyEditorSupport works good: http://empire5.com/development/binding-a-custom-object-in-spring-3/

I had error in MySQL (bad column in database).